# Why couldn't I open a new file in JVM sub process?

Tags: java, maven

I've found this problem when I try to extend `apache-maven` to make it support external downloader without check the checksums.

The expected external downloader is `axel` and my solution is rewriting `getTransfer` and `transfer` method in `maven-wagon` and adding switch for checking `checksums` in `aether-core`.

All works fine except that the new sub-process of `axel` created by `mvn` command tells me `No state file, cannot resume!`.

After I've read the source of `axel`, I figured it that it meaned could not access the `state` file with flags `F_OK`, which always with extension `.st`  and should be created with flag `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY` at the beginning.

My code is as following:

```
protected void transfer(Resource resource, String url, File output, int requestType) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    TransferEvent transferEvent = new TransferEvent(this, resource, 3, requestType);
    transferEvent.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    ArrayList cmdLine = new ArrayList(DOWNLOADER);
    cmdLine.add(output.getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath());
    cmdLine.add(url);
    File parent = output.getParentFile();
    if(!parent.exists()) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }

    Process process = runtime.exec((String[])cmdLine.toArray(new String[cmdLine.size()]), (String[])null, parent);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String stdout = br.readLine();
    float progress = 0.0F;

    for(float previous = 0.0F; stdout != null; stdout = br.readLine()) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(stdout);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            String stringProgress = matcher.group(1);
            progress = Float.valueOf("0." + stringProgress).floatValue();
            this.fireTransferProgress(transferEvent, buffer, Float.valueOf((float)resource.getContentLength() * (progress - previous)).intValue());
            previous = progress;
        }
    }

    br.close();
    if(progress != 100.0F) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        for(String stderr = br.readLine(); stderr != null; stderr = br.readLine()) {
            sb.append(stderr);
        }

        if(sb.length() > 0) {
            this.fireTransferError(resource, new Exception(sb.toString()), 5);
        }
    }

}
```

I guess it's might be problem of privilege, and the state of target directory looks like (PS: I'm the user named `simple` in my machine):
[image]

State of `mvn` command:
[image]

State of command `axel` is:
[image]

PS: Sorry for couldn't paste the text into this editor for `spam` reason, I've no idea why stackoverflow think this question could be something `spam`.

My question is could I create a new file in sub-process from a JVM ? If it could, how should I set the privilege ? And Is there any bugs or defects of this method I do not know yet?

Any suggestion would be appreciate, thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

So the question turns out to be simple. The real reason is the `-o` option passed to `axel`. If user specify this option, `axel` will try to load state file named with extension `.st` of its original name located in current directory.

However, I'm trying to download the entirely new file from remote repository and there is ofcourse no such state file exists.

When I remove this option, all things turn out to be fine.